# can a vector take over another vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

look at following code:

```
    vector<int> c{ 1,2,3,4 };
    int *p = &c[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << p[i];
    }
```

I could use a pointer to take over a vector, however when I want a vector take over another vector, it dose not work;

```
    vector<int> d(c.size());
    auto itd = d.begin();
    auto it = c.begin();
    itd = it;
    for (itd; itd != d.end(); itd++)
    {
        cout << *itd;
    }
```

**take over** another vector means I do not want to **copy** it, just like using a pointer like the first part; a bit like **move constructor**;
can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want `d` to actually take/own all of `c`'s data, or just provide a view of it? If the latter, why not `vector<int>& d = c`?

Comment: A move constructor will make the first vector dead. Is that what you want?

Comment: @NeilKirk yes!!! if it could achieve.

Comment: Why not use `std::move`?

Comment: @AndyG thanks. use a reference is a great idea.

Comment: @NeilKirk can you write it as an answer?

Comment: @NeilKirk thank you very much. I get it;

Answer (score 3):

If you want a vector to "take over" another vector use `std::swap`:

```
std::vector<int> v1, v2;
std::swap(v1, v2);
```

This way your vectors would exchange data with out unnecessary copies.

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e98fc19089077694)